# Git ignore is not ignoring folder

Tags: git, github, ignore

i have the following `.ignore` file:

```
user_resources/*
```

With the project looking like this:

However when i either delete or add a file to the folder it still pushes the changes of the folder.

I have done `git rm --cached -r  user_resources/`

But sadly it still does not work :S

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i have the following .ignore file:

It should be .gitignore

http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore